# reactjs universal-cookie package error when calling get()

Tags: reactjs, cookies, get, typeerror, universal

I have the following two components. They are in separate .js files.

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'
class Comp1{

   someFunction(){
      // Call google Oauth
      // get userinfo from Oauth response and set the token below
      var cookie = New Cookie();
      cookies.set('user', user, { path: '/' })
      this.props.history.push('/Comp2')
      window.location.reload()
   }

}
```

*---------------------------------------------------------*

```
import cookie from 'universal-cookie'
class Comp2{

   anotherFunction(){
       var user = cookie.get('user');
   }

}
```

The second component throws the following error:

```
TypeError: universal_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.get is not a function
```

How do I resolve it?

UPDATE: google oauth flow

Comment: take note that you are performing both client-side-routing via `this.props.history.push` and reloading the page afterwards (server http req) via `window.location.reload` - is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `var cookie = New Cookie();` will cause syntax errors.

Use `var cookie = new Cookie();` as JavaScript keywords as key sensitive.

Secondly, you are inconsistent with your case-sensitivity again with your imports:

> import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'
>
> import cookie from 'universal-cookie'

These will cause confusion. Your going to want to refactor that to standardize across the components. Example just opt with the capital 'C':

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'
```

Lastly, taking into consideration the case-sensitivity I have mentioned & as others have mentioned, you need to instantiate Cookie as [it is a class](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/blob/master/packages/universal-cookie/src/Cookies.ts). Here is how your components should look like:

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie';

class Comp extends React.Component {
  ...
  someFunction() {
    var cookie = new Cookie();
    cookie.set('user', "somecookie", { path: '/' })
  }
  ...
}
```

---

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'

class Comp extends React.Component {
    ...
    someFunction() {
        var cookie = new Cookie();
        console.log(cookie.get('user'));
    }
    ...
}
```

---

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/universal-cookie-react-components-8lc3m

Also, just FYI don't use Incognito for testing my sandbox

[image]

Comment: I am not following how creating another cookie in Comp2 will give me the cookie that was created in Comp1. Doesn't the second call to 'new Cookie()' in Comp2 create a completely new cookie w/o the 'user' data? I tried to run this locally and the get('user') always returns undefined, as this probably a new cookie.

Comment: no, the cookie is stored in the user's disk - not just on the browser. it does not "create a new cookie" it is the same cookie bound to the origin with the key `user`. you are simply instantiating `Cookie` (i.e., `new Cookie`) since it is a JavaScript class. you can read more on concepts of object-oriented programming & instantiation. it returns `undefined` on the first run because it most likely has not been set yet when console.log was invoked. hope this help, good luck

Comment: No, I verified that the 'user' is being set in Comp1. But when the flow gets to Comp2, the get() returns undefined.

Comment: @sotn looks ok to me: https://codesandbox.io/s/universal-cookie-react-components-8lc3m. I've updated my answer to include this sandbox and more information

Comment: I checked both sandboxes and they are indeed working. My issue could be my app flow. I added details to my OP about the full flow. I am calling Google oauth to get the userinfo and the flow then goes to Comp2.

Comment: it shouldn't be the case - it should be set regardless of any api consumption. the only reason it wouldn't work is if the cookies have not been set. I recommend checking your application tab under developer tools. you can review your cookies there under Storage section

Comment: you were right, the cookie was not being set. Probably because I was dumping the entire google resp in the cookie. Once I added just the fields I needed I could see the cookie. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome. you can still dump that entire response in but i suggest you `JSON.stringify` it (provided it is of JSON format which I can only assume) - just an example

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not calling `new Cookie();` in the second block of code, hence the methods like get and set are not initialized.

You can try this approach where you call new every time you want to access the cookies.

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'
class Comp2 {
   anotherFunction(){
       var cookie = New Cookie();
       var user = cookie.get('user');
   }
}
```

Or you could create a "global" variable that you access from anywhere.
Because you are accessing the `globalCookie` in separate files you would have to put the initializing code in a file that are called/imported before the files that contain your code that uses the `globalCookie` variable.
But please be very careful using globals as they are a easy way to introduce hard to find bugs in to your code.

```
import Cookie from 'universal-cookie';
var globalCookie = New Cookie();

class Comp1{
   someFunction(){
      globalCookie.set('user', user, { path: '/' })
   }
}
class Comp2{
   anotherFunction(){
       var user = globalCookie.get('user');
   }
}
```

See github repo for docs: https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie

Comment: please see my comment above, get() is returning undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have `import cookie from 'universal-cookie'` in your Comp2.
Replace it with `import Cookie from 'universal-cookie'`